# Get Distinct rows From C# Data Table with LINQ Comprehensive Query

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have Data Table of C#.Just want to Get the Distinct row list On a Column Property of this Data Table.Say , I have a Data Table with Columns property x,y & z.I have Rows 200 in that data Table which have same x values. I want to have DISTINCT row based on only x Column property with LINQ comprehensive Query where i am binding it to a list of model (I have).

I have a model

```
  public class Model
    {

      public Model(string x)
      {
          X= x;

      }
      public int X{ get; set; }
      public string Y{ get; set; }
      public decimal Z{ get; set; }

    }
```

And I am stuck with this comprehensive query.It should give distinct List But Not working as expected.

```
List<Model> modelList= new List<Model>();

        modelList= (from item in response.AsEnumerable()
                         select new
                         {
                             description = DataTableOperationHelper.GetStringValue(item, "description")
                         }).Distinct().Select(m => new Model(m.description)).ToList();
```

- Where DataTable response ( has 200 rows) and 'description' is one of its column property.

It gives a list but not DISTICT value of 'description' property.Is there anything That i am missing to consider ?
Stuck seriously .

Comment: what is the response object, please share the elaborated code here

Comment: Where 'response' is a DataTable ( has 200 rows) and 'description' is one of its column property.

Comment: Could you give a minimal example input that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @sloth ,I have simplified my question reducing some Part.See if you can help me.Beside that 
How can I Just DISTINCT a List "modelList" based on a Property 'x'.that will also help me.

Comment: @user3157277 Sorry, I don't see why your code should not work. That's why I asked for an example input that reproduces your problem. To use `Distinct` on a single property, you have to provide an appropriate `IEqualityComparer` to `Distinct` or use a `GroupBy`. There are probably 1000 questions on stackoverflow asking this.

Answer (score -1):

It's because this code

```
new
{
    description = DataTableOperationHelper.GetStringValue(item, "description")
}
```

creates new object with property "description" and it compares by reference but not by value of "description".

Try this:

```
ModelList = response.AsEnumerable()
 .Select(item=>DataTableOperationHelper.GetStringValue(item, "description"))
 .Distinct()
 .Select(x => new ConsumablesViewModel(x.description))
 .ToList();
```

Comment: It shows error : 'string' does not contain a definition for 'description' and no extension method 'description' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: *it compares by reference but not by value of "description".* That is wrong. `Equals` will be used, and two instances of the same anonymous type are equal if their properties are equal.

Comment: @user3157277 It's because `x` in the second `Select` is a string. `.Select(x => new ConsumablesViewModel(x))` would compile.

Comment: @sloth , do you have any Idea how can I solve this problem.Please help if you can.